# Can GCC only compile code for one specific architecture and operating system?

Tags: gcc

GCC is a compiler collection that generates machine code from different programming languages. For that you have to compile the compiler to run on your architecture and operating system. But you also have to define what kind of machine code and file format is generated.

Now my questions:
Is the output file of GCC only configurable at compilation time of GCC?

And can GCC be compiled so that it supports multiple architectures and file formats?

Comment: at a time yes, one build of gcc is meant for one target although like arm that could mean a lot of actual architectures, but within the arm umbrella.  if you want multiple architectures then you need multiple gnu builds.   file formats is not part of that you just use objcopy to convert to the various options.

Comment: So you have choose the group of architectures that the GCC-Developers have predefined when compiling GCC. And then for example with a x64 architecture if I want to compile an executable of my own code for Windows and one for Ubuntu can I choose that when compiling my code with GCC?

Comment: when you build a native gcc on an x86 running windows you get a tool that will build for windows, likewise on linux.  for cross compiling that one I know takes extra work not sure what the work is.  not this is a toolchain so compiler, assembler linker at a minimum the assembler and linker come from binutils not gcc, and then there is c library, etc.

Comment: if you have a gcc built for arm-none-gnueabi-linux it wont build for mips, x86, etc, nor even for the 64 bit arm that needs to be aarch64-whatever-whatever.  then when you get into abi and operating system and other details within a target then maybe the triplet (quadruplet?) helps and maybe not depends on the target, host, etc.

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. I didn't know that the assembler and linker are parts of binutils and not GCC. Is it correct that GCC generates assembly code so that for example the binutils assembler can assemble and link it?

Comment: yes that is correct, if you do a -save-temps you can see the intermediate files, gcc itself is a front end to the real compiler, there is some preprocessing of includes and defines into one big file then the real compiler works on that, and outputs asm which is then fed to the assembler and the objects to the linker unless you tell gcc not to do those things.   it is a toolchain basically compiler, asembler, linker, tools that are chained/linked together.  a simple/sane design

Comment: llvm on the other hand (while still simple/sane) but as an overall design the front end which both have is compiled into an intermediate code which both have, but in the case of llvm you can work with the itermediate code, you can save it, possibly even program in that language.  can do cross project/module optimization which other tools cant, and then eventually turn it into asm or object then link.

Comment: a stock no options llvm build will give you all the targets so you can build at least up to asm for any of the possible targets, now whether you can take it to object or a final binary that is not meant for the host platform, that is another story, I dont mess with it much anymore, but I would use binutils to finish up items built by clang/llvm and you could use the same clang/llvm for whatever target, didnt have to do a per target build of the tool.

Comment: which is my point on that topic for gcc/bunutils it is building a target specific compiler from the generic sources, the binary (the toolchain itself) is target specific, using separate directories for stuff you can have as many binary/target sets as you want.  with llvm/clang you only need one binary for most of the work and perhaps all of the work, maybe I simply didnt figure it out way back when.  it is natively a multi-target tool.  you can build it for one or a subset of all the targets if you wish

Comment: @old_timer You should turn these comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc and binutils are designed to build for one architecture/family at a time.  So if you build them as a cross compiler for ARM then you cannot build mips, but you can have multiple/many installations so you can also build one to target mips and use that one.

clang/llvm if when you build you don't tell it not to it will build a tool for all targets it knows.  This tool will get you up to the object level for any of the supported targets with the one tool, but linking is another story you need to tell it to builds its linker (and then I don't remember if the linker will support any target or one).  You can use binutils to assemble/link for clang/llvm (and then you definitely have a single target assembler/linker).